# ng-select weird behaviour

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue I have trouble understanding and maybe some can enlight me on the "why".

1. I retrieve a user from backend, let's say it looks like that:

   $scope.user
   {
     id:1,
     status:{
             id:1,
             label:test
     }
   }
2. I retrieve the list of all statuses from backend

   $scope.statusList =
   [{
     id:1,
     label:test
    },
    {
     id:2,
     label:toro
    }]
3. I want to display a select input, containing the list of statuses and preselected with the user status

On my template, I have the following:

```
<select ng-model="userStatus" ng-options="status.label for status in statusList"></select>
```

In my controller, I have tried the following

Case 1: preselection working

```
function findObject(listObject, Object){
    for(var i in listObject){
        if(listObject[i] == Object) {return listObject[i]};
    }
    return listObject[0];
}

$scope.userStatus = findObject($scope.statusList, $scope.user.status);
```

Case 2: not working

```
$scope.userStatus = $scope.user.status
```

Case 3: not working

```
$scope.userStatus = {id:2,label:toro}
```

Case 4: not working

on my template, I put the following directly

```
<select ng-model="user.status" ng-options="status.label for status in statusList"></select>
```

Why case 2 and case 3 won't preselect the select box???
And more importantly, case4 would be really useful to edit a user without copying everthing in a new variable, so why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because angular uses `===` (but `==` would have the same effect) and not `angular.equals()` to compare each option with the preselected option. Since you have two different objects, the comparison returns false, even though the objects have the same keys and values.

Several comments in the [documentation of `select`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) are talking about the problem you face.

Comment: So how do people do usually? They go with an intermediate value like in case1?

Comment: I guess so. I haven't seen many usages of Angular. Just starting to use it myself. Many times, you would just have the ID of the status in the user anyway.

Comment: Ok :'(. Quoiqu'il en soit, merci de votre aide JB Nizet